# Console output does not print the correct info as intended

Tags: java, class, object, println

the following code:

```
public class Drone {

    static int x;
    static int y;
    
    public Drone(int x, int y) {
        toString(x, y);
        System.out.println("X is "+x);
        System.out.println("Y is "+y);
        
    }
    public String toString(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("X is "+x);
        System.out.println("Y is "+y);
        return "Drone 0 is at "+x+","+y;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drone d = new Drone(5, 3);      // create drone
        System.out.println(d.toString());   // print where is
        
    }
```

Makes the line `System.out.println(d.toString());` seem to not print. As seen here:

[image: console output]

Answer (score 0):

The method `toString()` you invoke from main is not the `public String toString(int x, int y)` you've defined. Instead, it is the default implementation from `Object`, and that produces exactly the String you see in your output.

To add a custom implementation of `toString`, you need to override that implementation, which means you need to match the signature exactly (i.e. no parameters).

Something like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Drone 0 is at "+this.x+","+this.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toString method that you have written is expecting 2 arguments, which you have not passed. That's why it is calling toString of object class. If you want to call your method u need to pass the arguments.